# Minimal, but most important

Tags: phrase-requests, programming

I'm writing a [Priority Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). The details of it aren't important, but to describe a situation, I need a specific word.

It's possible for an item with the *lowest* priority to be *the* most important item in the queue.

As an example, say you have a task where the time left to complete it is the priority of the task. An item with less time left (assuming all work is equal) will have a higher priority.

The problem is expressing this idea in a few words coherently. If I wanted a function that creates a queue that prioritizes items of higher relational priority, I could call it `new-high-priority-queue`, or even just `new-priority-queue`. "Priority" just generally lends itself to urgency and an understanding that more == more.

How do I name a queue that prioritizes "low priority" items though? `new-low-priority-queue`? That sounds like all kinds of wrong. The best I could up with to express this idea was `new-inverse-priority-queue`, but that still sounds obscure. Of course I could/will add documentation, but it would be nice if the name of the queue spoke for itself.

Comment: It's about Location, Location, Location?

Comment: @GregLee I'm not sure what you mean. *Technically*, the highest priority items are at the front of the queue. I'm just grasping to find a phrase to describe what is considered a priority item when lower values of priority correspond to a higher priority in the queue.

Comment: This is typically called ***shortest/nearest deadline scheduling***

Comment: In retail pricing of real estate, where a house is located is all-important. That principle is referred to by "location, location, location".  I guess that is a more general idea than what you're looking for.

Comment: So, you're talking only about time-based priority. (There are many different criteria that could be used to determine something's priority—as well as its urgency.) Here, you're setting a priority that's inversely proportional to or calculated by (deadline-task completion time).

Comment: @JasonBassford Time was just an example, since it seemed to make the most sense. I'm actually going to be using this for Huffman Coding, so the "prioritized" items will be those with the lowest frequency in a body of text.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this inverse relationship between priority and importance. The two use cases that come to mind are a critical path algorithm where you do tasks that are blockers for other tasks, or tasks that are blockers for the longest running dependency chains, or a "slow execution" queue where you send non urgent tasks off to the slowest CPU in your cloud to get worked on whenever it has nothing better to do. Do either of those fit your use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert on computer programming by any means, but I've heard the terms **min heap** or **min priority queue** used to describe such queues that prioritize lower values.

I'm not sure if you would consider Wikipedia a valid source, but [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Operations) and [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/heaps-and-priority-queues/) are just a few examples of the terms "min heap" and "min priority queue" being used.

Comment: See [Max & Min Heap using C++ STL](https://codeconnect.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/max-min-heap-using-c-stl/)